# How to retrieve post data from view of django app

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, post

All I am new to jquery and Django.
I used the following code to post when the button with id 'submit_data' is clicked. Is it possible to retrieve the dictionary `{ data_key: 'myString'}` from the views.py of the Django app?
If yes how?

```
$(function() {

    $('#submit_data').on('click',function() {
        $.post('/url/', { data_key: 'myString'}, function(result) {
            alert('successfully posted');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For a POST request with form data, you can use `request.POST`:

```
def my_view(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # ...
```

For a POST request with JSON data, you need to decode `request.body`:

```
import json

def my_view(request):
    # TODO: missing a suitable `content-type` header check
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode())
    print(data)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

request.data is used to fetch data from your frontend

it is a dictionary-like object that lets you access submitted data by key name.

Try this:
request.data.get('data_key',None). 
To avoid KeyError, you can use .get() which provides value if key found else None is returned.

Comment: `request.data` is a Flaskism/DRF-ism and not a thing in plain Django.

Comment: @AKX you are correct. request.data is used in DRF. For plain Django, we can use request.body

request.data # Handles arbitrary data. Works for 'POST', 'PUT' and 'PATCH' methods whereas request.body is a bytestring. We need to decode it before using.

Answer (score 0):

In template script

```
$(function() {

    $('#submit_data').on('click',function() {
        $.post('/url/', { 'data_key': 'myString'}, function(result) {
            alert('successfully posted');
        });
    });
});
```

in views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.get('data_key', None)
```